# Avoiding need to call _.bindAll in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

From my reading it appears that when extending a Backbone.js class such as Model, a fairly common pattern is to call _.bindAll in the constructor as follows (see https://raw.github.com/eschwartz/backbone.googlemaps/master/lib/backbone.googlemaps.js):

```
GoogleMaps.Location = Backbone.Model.extend({
  constructor: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'select', 'deselect', 'toggleSelect', 'getLatLng', 'getLatlng');
    // etcetera
```

I do understand why this gets done, however the need for explicitly passing method names to _.bindAll seems to be a maintenance issue -- if you add new methods, you have to remember add them as an argument to _.bindAll as well.

Earlier today I posted a somewhat verbose solution to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977852/34806

However, shouldn't the following simple technique altogether avoid the need to call _.bindAll?  And that is, instead of the customary way of assigning "custom" methods, to instead attach them all to "this" within the constructor:

```
constructor: function() {
    this.foo = function() {};
    this.bar = function() {};
}
```

Are there any downsides to this technique?

Answer (score 1):

Your technique doesn't work, you still need to bind those methods like any other. Or use something like `var this = self` but then those methods cannot be used in sub-classes or anywhere else for that matter.

Just get rid of the bindAll altogether and `bind` just in time when you need it, e.g. when passing a method as a callback somewhere. It should be far easier on the maintenance because the chore is localized. Forgetting to bind when passing a method as a callback should eventually feel wrong like forgetting to use `var`.

Comment: Your suggestion to always call bind "just in time" seems unnecessarily inconvenient and verbose, especially in comparison to 'var' which you can use to assign multiple variables.  Thanks for pointing out my attempt wouldn't work though, I was coming to that conclusion.  Now I may think about overriding Backbone.Model.extend to take 3 objects (it currently takes 2, the second being for static properties), where the 3rd object can contain the methods that should be automatically bound.

Comment: Most of Backbone's and Underscore's methods that take a callback as parameter have an optional argument for the context which makes this JIT-approach more concise.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty it's not any more verbose than anything else, I think you are misunderstanding something. Instead of calling bind in constructor, you call it when passing it as event handler - exactly the same amount of verbosity, but with the latter it is localized and so maintenance is better.

Comment: @Esailija I understand ulle's comment and actually found it on my own and answered my own question.  Unfortunately you did not explain precisely what you meant by "bind just in time" -- I thought you were suggesting something such as an explicit call to _.bind *every time*, instead of passing this (or whatever the scope is) as an optional argument.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty `messages.on("reset", this.render, this);` vs `messages.on("reset", this.render.bind(this));` do the same thing, in same amount of code (ok literally, you are saving 5 characters), except the bind works in all cases and you don't have to figure out if a certain function accepts a context parameter, and if it does, which parameter slot that is. Don't you agree that there is far less cognitive overhead in just always using .bind rather than figuring out a context parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This that you need to explicitly pass in the names of the methods to [_BindAll](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) you want to bind is actually a pretty recent [change](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/commit/bf657be243a075b5e72acc8a83e6f12a564d8f55) as of underscore.js 1.5.0 - 7/6/13, if you look at the [change log](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog) for that release you'll see the following reason given for that change

> Removed the ability to call _.bindAll with no method name arguments.
>   It's pretty much always wiser to white-list the names of the methods
>   you'd like to bind.

That said it's probably better to do as [Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995876/esailija) says and just bind it *just in time* by utilizing the optional third parameter which keeps the bindings more localized.

Comment: Esailija does *not* seem to be suggesting utilizing the optional third parameter; see his last comment.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty the major points are gained by both methods, it's really a matter of opinion after that... I know I can always use bind without thinking about it so I prefer writing 5 characters over finding out/remembering if some API supports passing context parameter

Comment: @GeorgeJempty OK I see that I misunderstood what he originally said, however the idea is the same, that you are "binding" it just in time. Esailija is bringing up a second point that instead of needing to remember if the method takes a third parameter just use _bind when passing it in. Personally I don't really find it difficult to remember whether the method takes a third parameter (especially with intellisense...), but he does have a valid point.